# How to pass object between unrelated activates?

Tags: android

I need to pass an object between 2 activities that have no connection between them (meaning, neither of them calls the other).

My Main_activity extends TabActivity. I have 2 tabs : `CurrencyList` (extends ListActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener) and `CurrencyCalculator` extends Activity.

I also have class `currencyData` that saves data about different currencies.

In the CurrencyList activity I created a new currencyData object and initiate it with data.

How can I pass it also to the CurrencyCalculator activity?

Comment: Why don't you pass it using an Intent? or make it application member or static?

Answer (score 0):

2 quick ways:

```
1. use an static method in your activity to retrieve current ticket id
2. Design and implement an interface and register the fragments as listeners from the activity
```

Static Method is preferable for large data.

Answer (score 0):

If there is absolutely no connection between them, then one method of accessing data in different Activity classes would be to declare the data members as static class members. Keep in mind that static objects from Activities persist even after you destroy the activity and Android keeps this around for some time even after the you leave the application.

Answer (score 0):

These might not be the easiest ways (just some alternate approaches to the two answers given). You can  use a `Handler` or a `BroadcastReceiver` to pass the data to the other activity through an intent.

**Note**

- that your object would have to implement either Serializable or
  Parcelable if you want to pass it through an intent.  I have used
  Serializable before and as long as your object does not have any
  nested custom objects, you actually have to do no additional work.
- Also the assumption is that the receiving activity is alive and is
  able to receive the broadcast and/or message.

Another approach would be to write the object to a file (again it would need to be serializable) and read it back in the other activity.